# Baking soda inside PlayStation 4

Tags: ps4

I was cleaning my PlayStation 4 and I think I got a small amount of baking soda in the ventilation unit. Is this an issue? If so, are there any particular problems I can expect, and what should I do if I encounter one of them?
Update: In terms of on-screen stuff it seems to be running fine. When I listen to it, I can hear stuff going on, but that might have always been going on I just never paid attention to it before.

Answer (score 2):

Turn it off, and try and Hoover it out, the only problem I can anticipate is that if theres moisture, the baking soda will absorb it but hopefully enough didn't go in to cause any major problems.

Comment: what does hoover mean?

Comment: Sorry, Vacuum....

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do, is take the PS4 apart and then use an air duster to suck up the baking soda out of the ventilation.